# Is it possible limit the execution of a service in a specific time range?

Tags: nagios, check-mk

I'm using check_mk to monitor a system, one of the confiured services make use of *check_mk_active-http* to do HTTP POST to perform a login into a web application every two minutes.

I would like to disable this check from 10pm to 6am every day, I mean not only the notifications about failures but the login call itself.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since your question is about a service, please refer to the [Nagios Object Definitions](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/objectdefinitions.html#service), specifically that of the service object. A Service Object has a `check_period` that you can use to control during what time periods that check will run. From the manual:

> This directive is used to specify the short name of the time period during which active checks of this service can be made.